# Desktop screen zoomed in automatically right from boot time. In Settings, 'Zoom' is set to 'off'

Tags: fonts, display-resolution

I use Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome.

This problem first surfaced yesterday morning. I thought (for no logical reason) that some font zip files I'd downloaded the day before might be the problem so i changed permission to 000 for them and rebooted. Then the resolution was alright!

But, when i turned the desktop on this morning, it is again zoomed in!

I didn't install any software or download any files into any of my .local or other 'dot' directories yesterday.

In Accessibility, zoom is set to 'off'.

I searched the Web for "screen zoomed in Ubuntu" and looked at some answers. Don't see anything that seems to be applicable to my case.

Please excuse me if i am asking a question that's already been answered! Thank you.

Ramki

Comment: I did a "sudo apt update" and restarted and now the display is back to normal!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by unchecking "zoom" in the accessibility menu (on the top right of the boot screen - click on the shape icon).